# event is not working in go daddy server?

Tags: mysql

I am using Mysql event in my project and it is working fine in my localhost but the Godaddy not allow to

event_schedule = ON;

I have check event_schedule in go daddy it is showing off by using this command

show variables like '%event_scheduler%';

I used to set event scheduler on by this command

SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

but it is showing error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should check with godaddy support, not stackoverflow. However, most likely you have a shared hosting and godaddy may not be allowing users to change configurations at mysql server level.

Comment: Thanks for your response...I have talked with go daddy customer care executives and they gave some link of stackoverflow to resolve the issue. even some executives are unaware of events.